# Use more points to define imroi object

Tags: matlab

**In short:**
I was wondering if it was possible, when using ROI base classes ([imroi](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imroi.html) actually) such as  [impoly](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/impoly.html?searchHighlight=impoly), [imfreehand](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imfreehand.html) and others to increase the number of points (i.e. increase the sensitivity) generated by the [getPosition](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/imroi.html?searchHighlight=getPosition) method.

**Sample code:**

Consider the following code, in which I:

1) Read and display some image

2) Call `imfreehand` to draw a closed region of interest.

3) Call `getPosition` to get a Nx2 array in which the coordinates defining the freehand object I just draw are stored.

4) Call `scatter` to see what are the actual coordinates that were recorded.

```
clear
clc
close all

%// Read and display image
A = imread('coins.png');

imshow(A)

%// Set up imroi object
hROI = imfreehand(gca,'Closed',1);

%// Get its position as a Nx2 array
ROIPosition = getPosition(hROI);

%// Display the points retrieved by the getPosition method.
hold on

scatter(ROIPosition(:,1),ROIPosition(:,2),20,'r','filled')
```

After zooming on the ROI drawn, I get this:

[image]

which as one can see lack a couple points to fully describe the object.

To put in other words, is it possible to obtain a Nx2 array from the `getPosition` method where N is larger than the default (whose value I don't know)? I searched on the web but couldn't find anything relating to this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: If the points are ordered, you can loop through each pair of points and interpolate.  To prevent having crowded clusters of points you can skip this step for a pair if the distance between successive points is less than a threshold.  You'd have to store each set of points in a cell array as the size is going to grow, then combine them all with `cell2mat` after.

Comment: Ah yes @rayryeng that's a good idea I didn't think of that! You can post that as an answer if you like I'll certainly upvote it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is not too late, there is another alternative method to do get the coordinates by using `bwboundaries()` over the mask of the ROI object `hROI` you created.

Here is an example :

```
A = imread('coins.png');
imshow(A)
hROI = imfreehand(gca, 'closed', 1);
bw = createMask(hROI);
B = bwboundaries(bw);
B = B{:};
hold on
scatter(B(:,2), B(:,1),20, 'r', 'filled')
```